# C++ getting values from tuple<vector<Ts>...>

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates

I have a class Storage, where I have tuple of vectors. I want to be able to get values from it. How should I implement getRow()?

All vectors have always exactly the same length.

```cpp
template<class ... Ts>
class Storage
{
    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> m_col;

public:
    auto getRow(int row) {
        // get row-th element from each vector, put it together and return them as tuple
    }

    template<size_t I>
    auto getElement(int row) {
        return get<I>(m_col)[row];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `std::apply` (C++17), which is simpler than `index_sequence`s:

```
auto getRow(std::size_t row)
{
    return std::apply([&](const auto&... columns) {
        return std::tuple<Ts...>{columns[row]...};
    }, m_col);
}
```

Comment: That's nice! I've just come up with the same idea. :)

Comment: @Evg Well, now let's wait for Barry's [Generalized pack declaration and usage](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1858r2.html) to simplify this even more :)

Answer (score 2):

One possible implementation:

```
public:
    std::tuple<Ts...> get_row(std::size_t row) const {        
        return get_row_impl(row, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
    }

private:
    template<std::size_t... is>
    std::tuple<Ts...> get_row_impl(std::size_t row, std::index_sequence<is...>) const {
        assert(((row < std::get<is>(m_col).size()) && ...));
        return std::tuple<Ts...>(std::get<is>(m_col)[row]...);
    }
```

Alternative implementation with [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) and variadic lambda:

```
public:
    std::tuple<Ts...> get_row(std::size_t row) {        
        return std::apply([row](const auto&... vs) {
            return std::tuple<Ts...>{vs[row]...};
        }, m_col);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks :-) `std::apply` is powerful